# SQL Server : openquery insert linked server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

How do I insert data into a linked server (oracle) with a condition that a row does not exist?

I want to insert into `employee` table if `employeecode` does not exist yet in that table

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY(ORACLEX,
  'SELECT EMPCODE, EMPNAME FROM AX.EMPLOYEE') -- I want a where clause here

Select EID, ENAME FROM EMPDATA
```

Comment: why did you tag sql-server if you want an oracle solution?

Comment: This is a sqlquery, i am running it in MSSQL server just connecting to linked server.

Comment: Nobody knows the answer?? Oh God please help!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might actually have to read from the table twice

```
   INSERT INTO OPENQUERY(ORACLEX,
  'SELECT EMPCODE, EMPNAME FROM AX.EMPLOYEE') -- I want a where clause here
   Select D.EID, D.ENAME
     FROM EMPDATA D
LEFT JOIN OPENQUERY(ORACLEX,
  'SELECT EMPCODE, EMPNAME FROM AX.EMPLOYEE') OQ ON OQ.EMPCODE = D.EID
    WHERE QQ.EMPCODE IS NULL;
```