# SQL and IBMDASQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator

I'm trying to query a set of files.
Out of the 15 I have to query 3 of them are returning the error:
Msg 7314, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "IBMDASQL" for linked server "Server name here" does not contain the table "system.lib.file". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.

I am using SQL and made a linked server using the IBMDASQL driver.

Like I said, 3 files out of the 15 are only giving me this problem.

When I do a wrkobj on the files I see that public has all permission, and I've added the specific user account just in case.

When I connect using a basic ODBC and microsoft query I don't even see the file on the list. When I log directly into the iSeries I can see and manipulate the files. .

Now using the alternate file name. But getting an insert error. As asked, here is the code and then below the exact error.

```
INSERT INTO [PARKWAY-TRAIN].S60017.ORDERF912.NC_NURS_ORD_REF 
(RECORD_ID, NURSING_ORDER_CD, ORDER_DESCRIPTION, LONG_DESCRIPTION, ORDER_TYPE, FREQUENCY_CD, FREQ_PM_MAINT, NOTE_REQUIRED_STS, NOTE_TEMPLATE, TPL_STATUS, FORM_ID, PARAMETER_ID, COSIG_REQ)
SELECT STND.RECORD_ID, STND.NURSING_ORDER_CD, STND.ORDER_DESCRIPTION, STND.LONG_DESCRIPTION, STND.ORDER_TYPE, STND.FREQUENCY_CD, STND.FREQ_PM_MAINT, STND.NOTE_REQUIRED_STS, STND.NOTE_TEMPLATE, STND.TPL_STATUS, STND.FORM_ID, STND.PARAMETER_ID, STND.COSIG_REQ
FROM [MODEL2].TNICLN2.ORDERF143.NC_NURS_ORD_REF STND
WHERE STND.RECORD_ID <> 'D' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT HOSP.NURSING_ORDER_CD FROM [PARKWAY-TRAIN].S60017.ORDERF912.NC_NURS_ORD_REF HOSP WHERE HOSP.NURSING_ORDER_CD = STND.NURSING_ORDER_CD)
```

The error message:
OLE DB provider "IBMDASQL" for linked server "PARKWAY-TRAIN" returned message "SQL0104: Token . was not valid. Valid tokens: .
Cause . . . . . :   A syntax error was detected at token ..  Token . is not a valid token.  A partial list of valid tokens is .  This list assumes that the statement is correct up to the token.  The error may be earlier in the statement, but the syntax of the statement appears to be valid up to this point. Recovery  . . . :   Do one or more of the following and try the request again: -- Verify the SQL statement in the area of the token .. Correct the statement.  The error could be a missing comma or quotation mark, it could be a misspelled word, or it could be related to the order of clauses. -- If the error token is , correct the SQL statement because it does not end with a valid clause.".
Msg 7343, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "IBMDASQL" for linked server "PARKWAY-TRAIN" could not INSERT INTO table "[PARKWAY-TRAIN].[S60017].[ORDERF912].[NC_NURS_ORD_REF]".

If I run just the Select portion of the code, I get a return 503 lines to be exact. It only fails when I throw in the insert portion of the code.

IBM says to correct the token. I've got no clue as to which token is in error to correct though.

Comment: I found a way to get the data I need. Using FILELAY I was able to get the alternate file name and the query seems to be working. Anybody know why?

Comment: Not seeing the file on the list is a verification that the profile you are using for OLE DB is not authorised to the files.  Is the OLE profile the same as your user profile?  Are the files logical files based on PFs the profile is not authorised to?  How about the libraries?  How current is the IBM i on PTFs?  Finally, are you using a current version of the driver?

Comment: I'll have to ask to see how current the iSeries is on PTFs, I'm sure it's not current. The client drags it's feet unless its critical. Any idea what the current IBMDASQL driver is? My build is almost a year old, reporting Version 7. Any smart update or do I need to a reinstall?

Comment: Double check your authority. For Client Access, see http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/windows.html  There are basically 2 ways Access for Windows comes packaged. 1) As a directory in the IFS of the IBM i machine. 2) As a separate CD.  If you check your Service Level, you should see where it's pointing to get updates. If the IFS, putting the latest Access PTF will get you the latest driver when you do the Service Pack update.  Otherwise, have the IBM i admin download the latest service pack from the IBM ESS web site: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1010355

Comment: I updated to 7.1 (was on 7.0) and I still have to use the alternate file name. Which isn't an issue. I am having a problem inserting into these files though. I keep getting an invalid token error. .

Comment: Edit the question and post the code that is causing the error and the text of the error message.

Comment: @BuckCalabro Updated the question per your request. Thanks for looking.

Comment: If you can access the file directly on the server, please post the exact name of the file and library as you specify it _on the server_.

Comment: @user2338816 - The file in question has a name of NCORDER the alternate name I'm using to hit it with the IBMDASQL connection is NC_NURS_ORD_REF. I tried changing the insert command to ORDERF912.NCORDER but then I get a file does not exist error.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Table not found' error is very suspicious.  Using STRSQL:

```
select table_name, table_schema, 
base_table_name, base_table_schema, base_table_member, 
system_table_name, system_table_schema 
from systables 
where table_name = 'NC_NURS_ORD_REF'
```

Check to see that the table named NC_NURS_ORD_REF in library ORDERF912 is really associated with the system table name NCORDER in the library ORDERF912.

The syntax error is equally suspicious.  Given that this is a cross-system query, I doubt you'll be able to run it as-is from the IBM i STRSQL command.  That would mean that the proper multi-system database configuration is set up on the i side.

I found someone with a similar problem and it looks like it's on the Microsoft side: http://bytes.com/topic/db2/answers/447753-error-inserting-into-iseries-db2-table-long-name-via-sql-server-2000-linked-server  I think his workaround was to use the OPENQUERY() form.

One thing you can definitely check on the IBM i side is whether journaling is turned on for ORDERF912.NC_NURS_ORD_REF.  This is important because you need to use the right commit level.  Take the results of the previous query against SYSTABLES and use the SYSTEM_TABLE_NAME to do a DSPFD.  Look for the text 'File is currently journaled'.  If the table is not journaled, you have several choices.  The best choice is to start journaling the file, but if that's not available, try INSERT... WITH NC.  Or turn off commitment control at the driver.

Also, have a look at the following IBM technote to make sure the linked server is set up properly: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1014514

Comment: I don't have a problem doing a SELECT statement, and on 12 other files I don't have a problem doing a similar insert function.

Comment: I did fire up the iSeries Navigator and wrote out one of the rows to be written by hand (God help me if I have to do that for the other 502 rows x 40 more servers...) and executed the INSERT statement with no problems. So it has to be something on the MS SQL Server side. I tried to run the entire statement and run into the servers not being in each others relational databases. Any way I can work around this?

Comment: Check out the Bytes.com link.  Try the openquery form of the command.

Comment: I don't understand how to get that to work in MS SQL. I tried the openquery on the iSeries and it says that the target server isn't in the relational database.

Comment: I tired an OPENDATASOURCE with the query and got the same error message.

Comment: You didn't mention what version of SQL Server you're using.  Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391800/sql-server-openquery-insert-linked-server

Comment: I'm using MS SQL Express 2014.